# Shapefile of European Parliament constituencies?

Tags: shapefile, data, europe

Is there any shapefile (or similar vector data set) of European Parliament electoral constituencies? Some countries (e.g. Germany) are basically one constituency, but others (e.g. UK) are not. Is there any shapefile of all the constituencies in one file?

Comment: There's a non-georeferenced SVG file at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EP-constituencies.svg

Comment: Wondering whether you tried looking on the INSPIRE geoportal (http://inspire-geoportal.ec.europa.eu/discovery/)?

Comment: Today, I think a question like this would be much better researched/asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should try the open data stack exchange or at least tell us where you've looked...

Answer (score 0):

**Nomenclature of territorial units for statistics** (NUTS)

equals "administrative divisions of countries"

Shapefile or Personal Geodatabase.

**NUTS 2010** http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/popups/references/administrative_units_statistical_units_1

wiki

**First-level NUTS of the European Union**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-level_NUTS_of_the_European_Union

Comment: That's not the same as the European constituencies, though. Germany has only one constituency, but 16 NUTS1 units (the states), for example

Comment: UK vs European Constituencies are not same either but for European Elections they are used.

Comment: I don't understand how this is an answer to the question, though. The NUTS data is much more granular than the European constituencies. You would need a list of which NUTS units make up which constituency.

Comment: you can dissolve NUTS levels 4/5 boundaries as required.

Comment: Is the EP constituncies a subset of NUTS1/2? I can merge all Germany's ones into one that's OK.

Comment: NUTS is not suitable for EP constituancies. Just compare the NUTS3 levels for Ireland http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUTS_3_statistical_regions_of_the_Republic_of_Ireland and the Irish EP constituancies http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_(European_Parliament_constituency)

Comment: @Rory: In Ireland, the constituency boundaries *almost* fall together with county boundaries, which you can get in the [EuroGlobalMap](http://www.eurogeographics.org/products-and-services/euroglobalmap) open dataset. However, there are some counties that are split between different constituencies (see p. 7 of the [report by the Constituency Commission](http://www.constituency-commission.ie/report.htm)). Unfortunately, I think the answer to your question is: No, there is no shapefile of the constituency boundaries. If you roll your own, I think it would be great if you could share it here.

Comment: @Mapperz: NUTS only has [three levels](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/nuts_nomenclature/introduction). Smaller units are Local Administrative Units (LAU's), but they're not part of the NUTS framework and not available in the files you linked to. At any rate, the LAU boundaries don't necessarily coincide with the constituency boundaries (in Ireland, for instance), so really, this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/gisco_Geographical_information_maps/geodata/reference is the parent page to the NUTS 2010 link. It includes the required manuals and reference material